# asp.net mvc insert data in database and refresh partial

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a Comment Model and i want to add some comments to database using partial view ...what  i want is to refresh the partial view without refreshing all the view ..
What i get now is that when i insert data to database the date get stored in database  but i have to refresh the page to see it.. the partial view do not refresh instantally.

here is my code :

```
 //model
 public partial class Commentaire
{

    public int CommentaireId { get; set; }
    public string TxtCommentaire { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCommentaire { get; set; }
 }
```

the View Model :

```
public class CommentaireViewModel
    {
        public Commentaire NVcommentaire { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Commentaire> Commentaires { get; set; }
    }
```

the  Index View :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index_AddItem", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "productList" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Commentaire</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.TxtCommentaire)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.TxtCommentaire)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.TxtCommentaire)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.DateCommentaire)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.DateCommentaire)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NVcommentaire.DateCommentaire)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>


    <div id='productList'>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductListControl", Model); }
    </div>
}
```

teh partialview :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover display" cellspacing="0" id="OrderTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>txt</th>

            <th>date</th>

            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Commentaires)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TxtCommentaire)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCommentaire)</td>



                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { id = item.CommentaireId }) |


                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and finally the controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            CommentaireViewModel viewModel = new CommentaireViewModel
            {
                NVcommentaire = new Commentaire(),
                Commentaires = db.Commentaires
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }


        public ActionResult Index_AddItem(CommentaireViewModel viewModel)
        {

            db.Commentaires.Add(viewModel.NVcommentaire);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return PartialView("ProductListControl", db.Commentaires);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your ajax request fails because of exception caused by expected `Model` type for partial view and received one mismatch.

In you partial View you have: `@foreach (var item in Model.Commentaires)` which means that your `Model` has a `Commentaires` property.

In your return statement of controller action you have: `return PartialView("ProductListControl", db.Commentaires);` which means that you are passing `IEnumerable<Commentaire>` as a `Model` to you view. This contradicts with what type of `Model` you have in partial view.

**Possible solution:**

1. Change your `Model` type for partial view to `IEnumerable<Commentaire>`
2. Change `foreach` in partial view to `@foreach (var item in Model)`
3. Change `@{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductListControl", Model); }` code in view to `@{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductListControl", Model.Commentaires); }`

Comment: Great!  Think you verry much, i did  the first solution and it did worked ..  hope this will will help someone  ...  the code is working perfectlly you have just to apply the fist solution given by @Ivan Gritsenko

Comment: Thank you guys, this helped me for my problem too.